# Does deleting video files on my local drive delete them from Plex?

Tags: streaming

When I add files to my Plex account is it just mirroring my local drive or if I delete files on my local drive they will disappear from my Plex server as well?

Comment: When you add files to Plex, you are pointing to the location of the file, or the folder where your files live. If you delete those files, your movies list will be blank. No mirror. If you've ever created a simple web page, it's the same principle. You can insert <img> tags, but if you delete the image, the image disappears from your web page. That's what Plex does. It's a working software that points to the files you tell it to point to. Plex doesn't move or or copy (mirror) any files. There may be a cache, but it would be for buffering.

Comment: @ejbytes Do you happen to know of a service that stores files and will stream through Chromecast to a TV? All my Googling didn't help.

Comment: I assume you mean movies. Since you mentioned Plex I assume that you have some movies that you want to stream, but you don't have the space for them so you'd like a free place to store them and also stream them. Nope. There are many places to save movies or upload for free like Google Drive, OneDrive, many to list. But to stream on demand? Youtube? 1 and 1.5 TB external drives are cheap. You might be able to stream from them as a Plex folder on external drive. Any external FREE parking also carries risk of loss, closing, or modifying like YT may do.

Comment: YT modifies how?